# How to set focus on richeditbox in metro style app?

Tags: windows-8, setfocus

I have the following code:

```
 private async void SendMsg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 RichEditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, "");
 await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
       if(RichEditBox!=null)
       SendBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
    });
 }
```

but when clicked,the RichEditBox didnot got focus.What's wrong with my code? thanks

Sorry,I forgot add this code:"MsgWebView.NavigateToString("Hello  World!");".And I found the problem  lies in here.So the whole code is like this:

```
private void SendMsg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MsgWebView.NavigateToString("Hello  World!");
   SendBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);

}
```

How to solve this problem?
Best regards.

Comment: Are you trying to open the keyboard programmatically by setting the focus to the RTB?  Also, is this in desktop or Metro?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide on EditText soft keyboard windows 8 Metro Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714431/how-to-hide-on-edittext-soft-keyboard-windows-8-metro-application)

Comment: This is in Metro.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Programmatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.focusstate.aspx) option on FocusState (not Keyboard).

```
SendBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I found the problem is not the Keyboard,but the code :MsgWebView.NavigateToString("Hello  World!");I added this code in  the Click event,so the whole code is like this:Thanks for you answer.I found the problem is not the Keyboard,but the code :MsgWebView.NavigateToString("Hello  World!");I added this code in  the Click event,so the whole code is like this:'private  void SendMsg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MsgWebView.NavigateToString("Hello  World!");
       SendBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
    });
 }