# Windows 8 - Display soft keyboard when opening the charm search bar

Tags: keyboard, windows-8

In my application, I open programatically the charm search bar with this kind of code :

Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().Show();

But I would like to open the soft keyboard so the use can directly search text without having to touch the text input.

I understood that I can not control the keyboard, so I have to set the focus to the search text block.

Did anyone have to solve this kind of issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide Keyboard programmatically on windows8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129550/show-hide-keyboard-programmatically-on-windows8)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  Opening the soft keyboard MUST be triggered by a touch event.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129550/show-hide-keyboard-programmatically-on-windows8) for an explanation.