# Windows 8 - How to Dismiss Touch Keyboard?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing my app for Windows 8 in C#, and one very annoying thing is that the touch keyboard sometimes stays on screen even though all textboxes have lost focus.

I read the article [keyboard dismissal logic white paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx#invocation_and_dismissal_logic), which explains that when switching from control to control, the keyboard can stay on even though a control may not accept keyboard input. This would be my case because all my contents are hosted in either a GridView or a ListView. When the user clicks on any item on screen, the tap would land on these controls. This is very annoying because the keyboard takes half of a screen and there is no way to close the keyboard.

I have tried to set the textbox to be disabled and it had not affect. The only way to remove the keyboard is to set focus on a button, which is extremely hacky.

I thought I needed to do something with the "AutomationPeer", but I am not clear what exactly to do. Is there a way to override this behavior?

**Edit:**
I figured this out. The goal is to change to the control type of the GridView and GridView item not listed in the [whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx#invocation_and_dismissal_logic). Here is the code of the grid that I did that allowed me to dismiss the keyboard:

```
public class KeyboardUnfocusableGridView : GridView
{
    private class KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewAutomationPeer : GridViewAutomationPeer
    {
        public KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewAutomationPeer(GridView owner)
            : base(owner)
        {
        }

        protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
        {
            return AutomationControlType.Custom;
        }

    }

    private class KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewItemAutomationPeer : GridViewItemAutomationPeer
    {
        public KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewItemAutomationPeer(GridViewItem owner)
            : base(owner)
        { }

        protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
        {
            return AutomationControlType.Custom;
        }

    }

    private class KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewItem : GridViewItem
    {
        protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
        {
            var baseItem = base.OnCreateAutomationPeer();
            return new KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewItemAutomationPeer(this);
        }


    }

    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        var baseItem = base.OnCreateAutomationPeer();
        return new KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewAutomationPeer(this);
    }

    protected override Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new KeyboardUnfocusableGridViewItem();
    }
}
```

It's unfortunate that I need to write this much code to do a simple thing. This is definitely not optimal since I would need to do this for each of the `ItemsControl` that I need to use.

Comment: If all of your content is in a GridView or ListView, all you need to do is set the IsHitTestVisible property to false and your text boxes will not be able to accept focus, so the keyboard will not pop up. Unfortunately, you will also lose scrolling. Just an FYI...

Comment: Great solution, I was hopeless with this issue :). And the same technique works for ListView as well.

Comment: Can you please move your solution to an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list?  Thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. For reference, see also [Custom automation peers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj219211.aspx#oncreateautomationpeer).

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is set focus to any control that does not accept text entry. However, be aware that if the user manually showed the keyboard (as opposed to it automatically showing because a TextBox received focus) then the keyboard will remain open.

Check out this really good thread about the on-screen keyboard for more info:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/winappswithcsharp/thread/3c227262-1d2c-4382-9c50-5b71d2b5d823

Comment: This did not work as all my controls are in a GridView or a ListView. By default, setting focus on a control in a GridView or a ListView does not dismiss the keyboard. I think I have figured out a way, which I am posting it here shortly.