# Is it possible to hide the SIP (soft keyboard) in Win 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When the user edits a record, a XAML Popup shows a small form.

The software keyboard appears when the user gives focus to a TextBox.

This is good.

OnKeyDown (if <kbd>Enter</kbd>) I commit the user's changes.

After the changes are committed, I hide the XAML Popup.

The SIP remains visible even though the form is invisible.

What is the correct way to handle this scenario?

PS: this ( [Show/Hide Keyboard programmatically on windows8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129550/show-hide-keyboard-programmatically-on-windows8) ) is not a solution to this problem. That's because the question is wanting to prevent it from showing. I need it to hide.

Comment: did you find a good solution for this? please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the texbox before you hide the popup, move the focus to something that won't use the keyboard (like transparent 0x0 border), perhaps?